# Set a default offset for Cesiumjs Viewer DEFAULT_VIEW_RECTANGLE?

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm setting the Cesium default rectangle and and view factor, both of which work fine. However, I was hoping that I could modify the default pitch that is used to view that rectangle by about 45 degrees. When I tried to use the default offset for that purpose, it did not affect the default view at all.

Can anyone explain the correct way to set the default pitch for the camera's default rectangle?

```
const Cesium = window.Cesium;
window.CESIUM_BASE_URL = './';
const extent = Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-124.848974, 24.396308,     -66.885444, 49.384358);
Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_RECTANGLE = extent;
Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_FACTOR = 0.1;
// Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_OFFSET = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRange(0.0, -0.785398, 5000.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about setting up the camera to a different angle? Have you considered using Camera setView function?

```
const extent = Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-124.848974, 24.396308,     -66.885444, 49.384358);
viewer.camera.setView({
    destination : extent,
    orientation: {
        heading : Cesium.Math.toRadians(90.0), // east, default value is 0.0 (north)
        pitch : Cesium.Math.toRadians(-90),    // default value (looking down)
        roll : 0.0                             // default value
    }
});
```